# How do I handle punctuation in this Pig Latin translator?

Tags: java

The rest of the code is working perfectly but I cannot figure out how to prevent punctuation from being translated.

```
public class PigLatintranslator
{
    public static String translateWord (String word)
    {
        String lowerCaseWord = word.toLowerCase ();
        int pos = -1; 
        char ch;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < lowerCaseWord.length () ; i++)
        {
            ch = lowerCaseWord.charAt (i);

            if (isVowel (ch))
            {
                pos = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (pos == 0 && lowerCaseWord.length () != 1) //translates if word starts with vowel
        {
            return lowerCaseWord + "way"; // Adding "way" to the end of string
        }

        else if (lowerCaseWord.length () == 1) //Ignores words that are only 1 character
        {
            return lowerCaseWord;
        }

        else if (lowerCaseWord.charAt(0) == 'q' && lowerCaseWord.charAt(1) == 'u')//words that start with qu
        {
            String a = lowerCaseWord.substring (2);
            return a + "qu" + "ay";
        }

        else
        {
            String a = lowerCaseWord.substring (1);
            String b = lowerCaseWord.substring (0,1); 
            return a + b + "ay"; // Adding "ay" at the end of the extracted words after joining them.
        }
    }

    public static boolean isVowel (char ch) checks for vowel
    {
        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'y')
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I need the translation to ignore punctuation. For example "Question?" should be translated to "estionquay?" (question mark still in the same position and not translated)

Comment: Please provide some input cases that you're worried about, along with desired output.

Comment: instead of just creating a substring beginning at 2 and going to the end for your qu case, you should search through the string for punctuation / different characters and find the index where it appears, and then create a substring of only the values before that.

Comment: Easy enough. Make sure you call the method correctly, i.e. make sure the `word` parameter is actually just that, a *word*, not a sentence with things like punctuations and multiple words. Since you didn't show how the method is called, we can't help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andreas said, if the function is expecting only one word, it should be the responsibility of the calling function to ensure there's no full sentence or punctuation being passed to it. With that said, if you require the translator to handle this, you need to find the index of the string where the punctuation or non-letter character occurs. I added in a main method to test the function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(translateWord("QUESTION?"));

}
```

I added a loop into the qu case to find the punctuation being input, the two checks are to see if the character at position `i` is inside the range of a - z. The sub-string then only goes to the point where the punctuation is found.

```
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < lowerCaseWord.length(); i++) {
            if(lowerCaseWord.charAt(i) > 'z' || lowerCaseWord.charAt(i) < 'a') {
                break;
            }
        }
        String a = lowerCaseWord.substring (2, i);
        String b = lowerCaseWord.substring(i);
        return a + "qu" + "ay" + b;
```

This may need some tweaking if you're worried about words with hyphens and whatnot but this should put across the basic idea.

Here's the output I received:

```
$javac PigLatintranslator.java
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M PigLatintranslator
estionquay?
```

Comment: But then how would I add the punctuation to the translated word?

Comment: Edited to include the punctuation. Once you know the position in the string that the word ends and the punctuation occurs, you can format the substrings however you want.